How to implementing a garbage collector with the statepoint-example strategy in LLVM?
I’m new to LLVM and I’m trying to implement a garbage collector that uses the statepoint API. I have been reading all the documentation and I think I have an idea of the path ahead of me. However, I don’t feel confident about this being the right path.
I have not been able to find a runtime implementation that uses the state point-example strategy online. The LLVM docs mention examples in the repo under /llvm/runtime/, but they seem to be gone.
The following is my understanding of what I need to do:
I want to use the statepoint API over the gc_root because the documents recommend using it for new projects. I understand that I need to do the following:

Declare a custom GC strategy with UseStatepoints = true; and UseRS4GC = true or use the statepoint-example built-in strategy. I plan to use statepoint-example unless I hit a technical issue that prevents me from using it.

Annotate all my functions to use this strategy with setGC:
#include <llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h>
// ...
Function *fn = Function::Create(prototype, Function::ExternalLinkage, function_name, 
module.get());
fn.setGC("statepoint-example");


Use the RewriteStatepointsForGC transformation pass will automatically introduce annotations like @llvm.experimental.gc.statepoint and @llvm.experimental.gc.relocate.

Use the PlaceSafepoints transformation pass to automatically add calls to safepoint_poll at safe points.

My GC should have an initialize phase that is called before the application starts and uses GCFunctionMetadata::roots_begin() and end() from GCMetadataPrinter to access the stack maps. The stack map should be in the following format:
Header {
    uint8  : Stack Map Version (current version is 3)
    uint8  : Reserved (expected to be 0)
    uint16 : Reserved (expected to be 0)
}
uint32 : NumFunctions
uint32 : NumConstants
uint32 : NumRecords
StkSizeRecord[NumFunctions] {
    uint64 : Function Address
    uint64 : Stack Size (or UINT64_MAX if not statically known)
    uint64 : Record Count
}
Constants[NumConstants] {
    uint64 : LargeConstant
}
StkMapRecord[NumRecords] {
    uint64 : PatchPoint ID
    uint32 : Instruction Offset
    uint16 : Reserved (record flags)
    uint16 : NumLocations
    Location[NumLocations] {
        uint8  : Register | Direct | Indirect | Constant | ConstantIndex
        uint8  : Reserved (expected to be 0)
        uint16 : Location Size
        uint16 : Dwarf RegNum
        uint16 : Reserved (expected to be 0)
        int32  : Offset or SmallConstant
    }
    uint32 : Padding (only if required to align to 8 byte)
    uint16 : Padding
    uint16 : NumLiveOuts
    LiveOuts[NumLiveOuts]
        uint16 : Dwarf RegNum
        uint8  : Reserved
        uint8  : Size in Bytes
    }
    uint32 : Padding (only if required to align to 8 byte)

I can then map (optionally) the stack map into a data structure that is easy for my GC to consume.

The runtime should implement a function safepoint_poll called at safepoints (step 4) and use the data collected in step 5 to check if a garbage collection pass is required.


Can someone more experienced confirm whether I’m on the right path? It would be awesome if you knew where I could find an example implementation.
Thanks!
